# O que significa "de engano em engano"?

Tags: significado, expressões

O que significa "de engano em engano"?

De acordo o texto eu percebi que talvez queira dizer "erro depois erro"!

Pode ser isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, pode ser isso.  "De engano em engano", pode significar "com um engano após o outro".  "Engano" não é necessariamente a mesma coisa que "erro"  Veja o exemplo:

- "E assim, de engano em engano, de ilusão em ilusão, nosso casamento acabou durando 30 anos."

> - [**"engano"**](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/engano) 
>     substantivo masculino
>
>   1. .Ato ou efeito de enganar.
>   2. Artifício empregado para enganar.
>   3. Ilusão.
>   4. Burla, logro.
>   5. Traição.
>   6. Erro de quem se engana.